# Finding fixed points of a system of difference equations

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear, difference-equations

Can anyone help me in finding the fixed points of the systems satisfying all the parameters are real, positive?

$$x_{n+1}=x_{n-d}e^{(r(1-\frac{x_{n-d}}{k})-\frac{\beta y_{n-d}}{(x_{n-d}+\gamma)}+x_{n-d}z_{n-d})}$$

$$y_{n+1}=y_{n-d}e^{(1-\frac{ay_{n-d}}{(bx_{n-d}+c)}-e+y_{n-d}z_{n-d})}$$

$$z_{n+1}=z_{n-d}e^{(-s+\frac{x_{n-d}}{y_{n-d}})}$$

```
Solve[x Exp[r (1 - x/k) - (\[Beta] y/(x + \[Gamma])) + x z] == x && y Exp[1 - (a y/(b x + c)) - e + y z] == y && z Exp[-s (x + y)] == z && r > 0 && k > 0 && \[Beta] > 0 && \[Gamma] > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && e > 0 && s > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

Output shows no solution exists. But I could see solution satisfying the conditions. Did I make any mistake?

Comment: To solve a recurrence, you would use `RSolve`. However, I am not sure if this is possible with a symbolic delay `d ` . Solve treats e.g. `x[n]`as a single symbol.

Comment: The equations for $z$ in your `Solve` expression does not match your third recursion equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to look for the zeros of the exponentials:

```
Solve[r (1 - x/k) - β y/(x + γ) + x z == 0 &&
      1 - a y/(b x + c) - e + y z == 0 &&
      -s + x/y == 0, {x, y, z}, Cubics -> False] // FullSimplify

(*    {{x -> Root[..., 1],
        y -> 1/s Root[..., 1],
        z -> ...},
       {x -> Root[..., 2],
        y ->  1/s Root[..., 2],
        z -> ...},
       {x -> Root[..., 3],
        y -> 1/s Root[..., 3],
        z -> ...}}             *)
```

If you don't want to work with [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects, you can convert them to regular radicals with [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html).

You'll still have to find out which one of these three solutions is the stable fixed-point of your recursion.